# Rewriting A Clean Name On Save And Updating The URL

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, angular-ui-router

I am using a clean name pattern to express an object from MongoDB, in the URL, with the help of ui-router.

http://192.168.2.11:8080/games/"*2000-risk-global-domination*"/

When I update that object using Angular Resource, I have updated the clean name in the $scope (and removed unfriendly characters)

```
        $scope.item.clean = ($scope.item.year + '-' + $scope.item.title.split(/[\s:]+/).join('-')).toLowerCase();
```

I can properly update the object with the new clean name in the database... What would be the best way to update the URL with the new clean name?

Use $stateParams to update the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently able to use $state.go('backend.edit', { id: $scope.item.clean }); Which reloads the route and data.

If anyone can post a better way to change the URL without the roundtrip call to the DB, please let me know.  Thank you